# Non uniform freezing of lakes

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

Here's a problem from my physics textbook:

Why do lakes freeze first at the surface?

I'm not sure why this should happen, and my guess is that the only reason for this could be the temperature distribution with depth, inside water bodies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know that water at $4^{\circ}$C achieve its highest density. So naturally, water at $4^{\circ}$C will tend to move to the bottom of the lake as it is heavier. When the temperature is cool enough to freeze the lake, eventually there will be some layer of ice forming at the surface but there is still liquid water below the ice layer. The ice also works as an insulation to keep the water below it from freezing to ice completely. Also, ice has a lower density than water so any ice forming will float to the surface. There are other factor like Earth's internal heating that constantly maintaining the water at the bottom of lake from freezing.